# bootstrap carousel showing multiple slides at once in one of two carousels on page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page with multiple Bootstrap carousels. For one of the two I want it to show two slides at a time (out of 5 or 6) on 768 and up, and the other should always be the standard behavior - showing one slide of the multiple in the slideshow. I found an answer and bootply here that does exactly what I want for the two slide carousel - as long as it is the only carousel on the page.

I can modify the jQuery so it only targets the one I want, but when I change the CSS to affect only the "two up" it gets jerky.

http://www.bootply.com/rMUxMAmkGe - With CSS targeting the top slideshow and a jerky top slide with one staying static.

http://www.bootply.com/dhDQgNnqxD# - Original CSS that does not target top slideshow. With this the bottom slideshow has the sliding action snap to 50% first, then slide the rest of the way.

Lastly, I will be doing this in Wordpress and know that referencing jQuery with an $ will be an issue - but I can probably figure that out as long as this gets fixed.

Comment: Surely a carousel with one slide is not a carousel - it's a static image?

Comment: One image showing at a time,  vs two images showing at a time.

Comment: Doh! OK, much clearer now after edit.